# Swift Optional Type Syntax

Tags: swift, option-type, optional-variables, optional-values

According to Apple's Swift guide, when you have the following Array and the following function to search through an Array:

```
let namesArray = ["John", "Lisa", "Bill", "Jennifer"]

// Note this function is set-up to return an OPTIONAL Int:
func findName (personName:String, arrayToSearchIn:String[]) -> Int? {
    for (indexOfName, nameValue) in enumerate(arrayToSearchIn) {
       if nameValue == personName {
          return indexOfName
       }
    }
    return nil
}
```

...so you can capture the Optional Int returned by this function - and then check to see if its `nil` or not - in the following manner:

```
let nameIndex: Int? = findName("Lisa", arrayToSearchIn: namesArray)
if nameIndex {
    println("found \(namesArray[nameIndex!])")
}
else {
    println("NOT found")
}
```

This is all good - but their next example, in which they streamline the code by collapsing the 2 statements into one - confuses me because they suddenly drop the Optional "?" and "!" from their syntax:

```
if let nameIndex = findName("Lisa", arrayToSearchIn: namesArray) {
   println("found \(namesArray[nameIndex])")
}
```

And this works perfectly well.

So why is it that in the first example `nameIndex` was declared with a "?" - like so:

```
nameIndex:Int?
```

and the forced-unwrapping occurs using a "!"

```
[nameIndex!]
```

but in the second example neither "?" or "!" one is used in the syntax?

Answer (score 3):

The handling of the declaration in an `if let` is special; one should treat it as its own language construct (not as a simple combination of `if` and `let`).  In

```
if let nameIndex = findName("Lisa", arrayToSearchIn: namesArray) {
   println("found \(namesArray[nameIndex]")
}
```

the type of `nameIndex` does not need to be expressed because it can be inferred as the return type of `findName()` which is `Int?`.  In the body of the `if let ...` the value of `nameIndex` is not bound to an *optional* and thus unwrapping is not needed - the value will be an `Int`.

Here is an example of how the `if let` binding is treated.  Notice that an explicit declaration of the type is essentially ignored:

```
> func test () -> Int? { return 111 }
> if let x : Int? = test () { return x }
$R6: Int? = 111
> if let x : Int = test () { return x }
$R7: Int = 111
> if let x = test () { return x }
$R8: Int = 111
```

but if you try to be so 'flexible' outside of an `if let`, you draw an error from the compiler:

```
> let y : Int = test ()
<REPL>:33:15: error: value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; 
   did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

Comment: (Sorry for the Edit) So I get what you're saying about not needing to explicitly declare the type for `nameIndex` because Type Inference takes care of figuring this out automatically - but then shouldn't this apply in *both* cases? Why is it that in the first case we _do_ have to specify that we want an Optional and that we want to Force-Unwrap it - but in the  second, truncated `if let` statement we don't have to do this?

Comment: It is because the `if let` is doing the unwrapping for you by binding `nameIndex` to its actual value.

Comment: @sirab333: In your first code, `nameIndex` has type `Int?`. You can explicitly specify the type or let it infer it; both will work. In your second code, `nameIndex` has type `Int`. Again, you can specify it explicitly or let it infer it. Because in the first case it is `Int?`, it needs to be unwrapped. In the second case it is already `Int`.

Comment: @newacct: this doesn't add up: in both cases, `nameIndex` is ultimately assigned the value returned by the function `findName` - which is explicitly declared as returning an Optional `Int?`, not a regular Int. And so it both cases, wouldn't `nameIndex` _also_ end up being of type `Int?` - either because it too was explicitly declared as such or because it would be _inferred_ as such given that its capturing the `Int?` being returned by the function? OR, are you saying that _any_ var declared as a regular var and not as Optional, _automatically_ force-unwraps whatever it is being assigned?

Comment: @sirab333: In the second case, `nameIndex` is not "assigned the value returned by the function findName". It is the special `if let` syntax. It is not the same as doing a `let` and then testing the variable. In `if let foo = bar`, if `bar` has type `T?`, then `foo` has type `T`. `foo` is only assigned if `bar` is not `nil`, and then only then unwrapped into `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

`?` is the operator to explicitly declare an optional type. `!` is the operator to force-unwrap an optional. The syntax in the example is a special Swift shorthand for checking and unwrapping in one concise line. It says, “assign `nameIndex` to the result of `findName(...)`, and if it is not `nil`, run the following code: ...”

Comment: I appreciate you taking to time to answer this, but I'm afraid you misunderstood my question. I wasn't asking what `?` and `!` do.  I know what they do - and I totally get the shorthand being used here. I was asking why  `?` and `!` had to be used in the first example but not in the second, short-hand example. It seems that Type Inference ought to work for both, not just for one but not the other. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don’t know how type inference works in the first example. What happens if you remove the type entirely? I believe if you declare it as `Int` instead of `Int?`, you will get an error, but what if you leave off the type entirely: `let nameIndex = findName("Lisa", arrayToSearchIn: namesArray)`?